# stop spark createdataframe(pandas.df) from stripping / trimming strings

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

When i convert a pandas data frame to spark, spark automatically strips the String columns/ deletes leading and trailing spaces. How can this be stopped?
`sparkframe = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)`
Example '  ' -> '' or 'ab ' -> 'ab'

Answer (score 1):

.option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace",False).option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace",False)
when saving is the the solution. Why its default True is a mystery